# Linked image in HTML (both wrapped and internal link) won't 'link'

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I'm working on a site that has a "switch" (just an images linked to a different version of the site). The image will show up, but it wont be clickable. After some troubleshooting, I also discovered it was clickable before I put any CSS or internal styling in. The image is using both a wrapped link and an internal link.

Code:

```
<a href="aboutOff.htm">
<div style="position:absolute;left:90%;float:right;">
<img src="on.jpg" href="aboutOff.htm" alt="Switch" id="switch" style="z-index:12; float:right;"/>
</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#switch{
width:119px;
height:auto;
z-index:10;
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: An A-tag wrapped in an A-tag is invalid HTML.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Try explaining it better please :). Are you wanting to make the image itself clickable? Also, I agree with Diodeus

Comment: @diodeus Changed, but still won't work.

Comment: @hunter Exactly! I just want the image, when clicked, to go to a new site.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Put the anchor tag inside the div.

Comment: IMG tags do not have href attributes, or alt tags either. Your inline styling overrides your CSS and you're combining absolute positioning with FLOATS. You need to go back to basics and do some reading.

Comment: @Diodeus, I'm only starting out and don't know absolutely everything, but you are wrong about the alt attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: @j08691 Sure! on it now

Comment: Yes, you're right on the ALT tag. Start without any styling and build it up from there.

Comment: @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/DGfhk/ This uses APAD1's code

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="switchContainer">
    <a href="aboutOff.htm">
    <img class="switch" src="on.jpg" href="aboutOff.htm" alt="Switch"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.switchContainer {
    position:absolute;
    left:90%;
}

.switch {
    width:119px;
    height:auto;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and the hyperlink still won't work. Thanks for helping anyways! Any other ideas?